# Mailx or mail command is not including the body when triggered via crontab

Tags: cron, mailx

I created a script that checks the process of apache server and sends an email if the process is down.

```
apache_down=`service httpd status | grep "inactive (dead)"`
echo “$apache_down" | mailx -s “APACHE_DOWN_`hostname`” abc@gmail.com
```

The script works fine when run manually - it sends the mail with the correct subject and body "$apache_down".

However when I place it under crontab, it sends the mail only with the subject and not the body.

```
*5 * * * * script.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

The body is empty with just "" . I used mail -s and same result. 
Is this an issue with my script or crontab or mailx set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the **$PATH** variable if its properly set for executing commands , if not then set it in your script or generally for cron.If $PATH is not set properly for binary then , ***service*** command will not run or you have to add it manually by executing it as **/usr/sbin/service**

Also try to add the check if variable has some output inside script...

```
if [[ -n "$apache_down" ]]
then
echo “$apache_down" | mailx -s “APACHE_DOWN_`hostname`” abc@gmail.com
else
echo "apache running fine" | mailx -s “APACHE_Running_`hostname`” abc@gmail.com
fi
```

Comment: Yes, I do have a check condition for that. It works fine when I run the script on command line. 
Just that the crontab is sending the message with an empty body

Comment: can you try :  mailx -s “APACHE_DOWN_`hostname`” abc@gmail.com<<MESSAGE  $apache_down                                                                                                        MESSAGE

Comment: Try adding service with full path "/usr/sbin/service" and try print the variable output in a temp file and check what it holds...

Comment: I modified it to the following:
mailx -s “APACHE_DOWN_`hostname`” abc@gmail.com <<MESSAGE $apache_down MESSAGE

Getting a syntax error :
warning: here-document at line 12 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `MESSAGE')

May be I am missing something.

Comment: Found that the issue was with the $PATH. I added the $PATH from the profile and it worked.
Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Pleasure.Yes thats why i mentioned to use full path for all the command like "service" , is that the reason? Please let me know.

Comment: Also sorry , i just seen your issue you commented yesterday .anyways that doesn't matter now..

Comment: No worries.Yes the $PATH for service was the reason.

Comment: Can I edit the answer to what I mentioned for the path and PATH variable ...so that anyone can get use of it ... Thank you

Comment: Yes. Please do update the Answer